# Add an end marker on button press

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have an android app that gets my location and displays a marker on it. It also tracks the device location locally and draws and marker on it, it also connects the markers with a poly line (This is just for accuracy testing).

My question is that when I press the button Finish Journey how do I get it to display a markers saying end location or something similar.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

    //Adds a marker on the current position found in LatLng
    final LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    LocationMarker.setPosition(myCoordinates);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myCoordinates));
    float zoomLevel = 12.0f;
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCoordinates, zoomLevel));

    //Adds marker on each location update
    points.add(myCoordinates);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myCoordinates));

        mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .addAll(points)
                .width(5)
                .color(Color.RED));

    //Button used to get and display ending location
    Button stopLocBtn;
    stopLocBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopLocBtn);
    stopLocBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final LatLng myendCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            points.add(myendCoordinates);

            LocationMarker.setPosition(myendCoordinates);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(myendCoordinates)
                    .title("End location"));

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, TrackingActivity.this);
        }
    });
}
```

This is what my onLocationChanged function looks like. My location updates are being saved in a Global ArrayList called points.

[image: Sample of what it looks like when ran]

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I want to add a marker for an end location when I press the button.

Answer (score 0):

1. You put `LatLng myCoordinates` as a global variable to store last location in `onLocationChange`

```js
    LatLng myCoordinates;
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
      myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    });
```

2. Draw marker when click `finished journey` button
3. Declare finished button in `onCreate` of Activity

```js
//Button used to get and display ending location
    Button stopLocBtn;
    stopLocBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopLocBtn);
    stopLocBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            points.add(myCoordinates);

            LocationMarker.setPosition(myCoordinates);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(myCoordinates)
                    .title("End location"));

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, TrackingActivity.this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have that done but it hasn't changed the output. Whats happening is the blue dot under the marker does not move from the original position but the poly line is getting drawn on the new location update. Any ideas?

Comment: You use a variable as `isStoped = false`, when finished button is pressed, `isStoped = true`, if true, map don't draw marker and polyline, if false, continue draw polyline.

Comment: I have the poly line stop when I press the button. The problem is that it only places one markers. I want one to be placed when I start the app and one to be placed when I hit finish.

Answer (score -1):

do you mean to create a marker in different colour or style? You can set icon on MakerOptions.

Try to create new icon with BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(float hue) with one of the BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_xxx values.

Comment: No I have different style markers. I want a marker to be placed on the last location update when I press the finish journey button.